# Как сделать так чтобы при парсинге яндекс браузер не думал что я бот?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
код
url = 'https://yandex.ru/search/? 
text=что%20такое%20уран%20вещество&lr=28&clid=2349563&win=430&src=suggest_B'
user = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.663 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}

full_page = requests.get(url, headers=user)
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'lxml')

con = soup.findAll("div" )
print(con)
```

при первом запуске было все нормально, но дальше он выводил "...Нам очень жаль, но запросы с вашего устройства похожи на автоматические...."

Comment: Ну, не браузер думает, а поиск яндекса. Там же тоже сидят люди, думают, как ботов отсечь. Сложно сказать, на что они ориентируются, надо смотреть, пробовать.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас запросов не очень много, воспользуйтесь специальным XML API. (Кажется, до 1000 запросов в день, он был бесплатный.) https://yandex.ru/dev/xml/

Comment: общая картина такова, есть голосовой асистент ему зается вопрос он ищет в браузере в моем случае yandex, в браузере дается ответ, я хочу что бы он озвучивался и все это в exe что бы вставил в любой пк(условно) и он работал

Comment: а с xml api это будет работать только на моем пк

Comment: Попробуйте заключить договор с яндексом. Возможно, будет достаточно упоминания что "на основе поиска яндекс".

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не сможете постоянно набирать это ручками
[https://yandex.ru/search/?text=что%20такое%20уран%20вещество&lr=28&clid=2349563&win=430&src=suggest_B](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&lr=28&clid=2349563&win=430&src=suggest_B)

Я не разбираюсь в тонкостях но от вас должны приходить куки, и ещё некоторая информация.
А не только User-Agent.

Какие заголовки отправляет браузер, можно посмотреть в браузере.
Где именно и как, зависит от браузера.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте выполнить запрос в браузере и в консоли разработчика посмотреть, какие хедеры отправляются. Добавьте в ваш запрос некоторые из них. Если не поможет -- единственный выход, который я вижу -- использовать Selenium.

Comment: Наверное, минусуют ваш ответ потому, что на ответ это не тянет, только на комментарий